# Как заставить FindWindow работать?

Tags: c#

```
System.TypeLoadException: "Не удалось загрузить тип "Nioka.Form1" из сборки "Nioka, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", так как метод "FindWindow" не имеет реализации (не имеет RVA)."
```

код

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Nioka
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
     
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lp1, string lp2);
        public void ControlAnotherProgram()
        {

            string notepad = "Notepad";
            //находим хендл главного окна
              IntPtr mainWindow = FindWindow(notepad, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Как заставить FindWindow работать?

Comment: Хорошо, только код который вы написали у себя в проекте, ванга пока не предсказывала.

Comment: Моя Ванга прозревает неправильно прописанную сигнатуру P/Invoke.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, надо поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибут кто писать будет?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Порядок аргументов тоже немного другой, если искать по названию окна

```
IntPtr mainWindow = FindWindow(null, notepad);
```

Comment: Атрибуты он красным подчёркивает скрин https://yadi.sk/i/DexsNbIa6ZP2Fg и куча ошибок вылезла скрин https://yadi.sk/i/StVRQx3_mBI2Lg

Answer (score 0):

Заработало.
Написал вот так

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Nioka
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
   ControlAnotherProgram();
        }
        public void ControlAnotherProgram() 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Standard Numeric Format Specifiers");
            string notepad = "Notepad";
            //находим хендл главного окна
              IntPtr mainWindow = FindWindow(notepad, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Добавил

> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;